# Are there any scientific evidence about benefits or harms of laughing a lot for babies

Tags: infant, development, emotional-development

We sometimes make our 7 months old baby laugh. And, at these moments he laughs a lot, which we think is good for his development. However, I want to support this claim with some empirical research findings.

I wonder if there are any scientific studies on this topic?

Comment: I don't have time to research this for a full answer, but there's a *ton* of research on laughter in babies.  [This TedTalk](https://ideas.ted.com/meet-a-scientist-with-a-most-delightful-job-he-studies-baby-laughter/) might be a good place to start looking, or some of the references in [this paper on parental affect](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4424150/) might also be good places to look.  There's no question that it's good for development to laugh - emotional, if not intellectual, development for sure.  Someone may just need to find the studies for you.

Comment: One note though - *tickling* induced laughter is a bit different from other things, from what I've seen.  Tickling laughter is a reflex, and can actually accompany feelings of pain or unhappiness but still include laughter - not always, or not even often for most kids, but do be aware it's different from laughter brought on by an emotional state or a reaction to something they perceive visually or orally.

Comment: Consider doing this just before the diaper change, rather than just after; bladder control may not really be there yet.

Comment: "We sometimes make our 7 months old baby laugh..." How do you do that? Peek-a-boo? Funny faces? With toys? Tickling? It matters. Thanks.

Comment: A bit of a reframe: laughing, as opposed to _what_? Crying? Not engaging your child? Avoiding emotion altogether? Doing things they don't like? Depending on what it is you're trying to home in on, you're going to get a different answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the specific studies.  However from an evolutionary standpoint we know both laughter and smiles evolved as a key part of parent-child interaction.  This is the way babies that can't yet communicate express their approval of an activity.  Laughter decreases as one ages, and this is largely because it's need is superseded by language and direct communication once verbal skills develop sufficiently.  In short evolution itself is encouraging laughter as a form of communication meaning it's unlikely to be harmful.

Comment: @joe tickling is indeed unique as it's the one form of laughter that may not be good and adults should make clear to children they have the right to 'opt out' of tickling and they will be respected.  Going back to my evolutionary discussion though tickling evolved as a mean to train children to protect vulnerable parts of their body from attack.  They laugh to encourage adults to keep up the 'training', but they may not enjoy it since their suppose to be learning how to protect against tickling and thus defend these body parts.

Answer (score 2):

As a parenting coach, I believe that laughter plays a significant role in a baby's development. While there may be limited scientific research specifically focusing on the effects of laughter on infants, I have witnessed its benefits firsthand. Laughing during playful interactions not only brings joy and happiness to babies but also contributes to their emotional well-being. It creates a positive atmosphere and helps build a strong emotional bond between babies and their caregivers.

However, it's important to strike a balance and be mindful of excessive laughter. While laughter is generally beneficial, it is crucial to pay attention to a baby's responses. Too much excitement can potentially overstimulate a baby, leading to fatigue or irritability. As a parenting coach, I advise parents to observe their baby's cues and provide support and comfort when needed. It's essential to create a safe and nurturing environment where laughter can flourish without overwhelming the baby.

While scientific studies on the specific benefits and potential harms of laughing a lot for babies may be limited, laughter is considered a natural and positive aspect of human development. It promotes social engagement and helps babies develop a sense of joy and happiness. Laughing together with your baby strengthens the parent-child relationship and contributes to their healthy social development.

As a parenting coach, my recommendation is to incorporate laughter into your daily interactions with your baby. Find joy in the little moments and engage in playful activities that bring smiles and laughter. However, always be attuned to your baby's needs and adjust the level of stimulation accordingly. Remember, each baby is unique, and what may be enjoyable for one may not be the same for another. Trust your instincts, provide a nurturing environment, and enjoy the beautiful moments of laughter and connection with your little one.

Answer (score 1):

In medical terminology how people (including children) look and behave would be called how they're 'presenting'. A healthy appearance and healthy, normal behavior would be called 'presenting as normal', which is an indicator, not cause, of good health.

One of the reasons there likely isn't much research on this topic is because laughter is an outward behavior (and indicator) with minimal links to physical function or health. In other words, most researchers wouldn't consider this a very important question, and it would also be difficult to decouple any impacts of laughing with the quality of the environment causing that laughter.

So as an indicator, if your child is laughing with joy regularly (note the word joy, as the other answer suggests there are other types of laughter) that's a sign that they're living in a secure and warm environment, with strong attachments. It would be an outward sign that development is going well, not a major (note the word major) cause of development outcomes.